# update HTML content in process address space

Tags: c++, c, windows

Everyone!

How can I change a HTML string displayed in a web page by modifing the memory of the browser process?

I did like this,but it did not work:

1. In chrome or IE, I open a web page,containing a string "google".
2. Open this chrome or IE process and search the whole memory space of the process for string "google", so I get an memory address `0x01960064`.
3. I wrote another string, such as "baby" to this address via API  `WriteProcessMemory`. But in the page, the string "google" did not change to "baby". Then I went to `0x01960064` and here was "baby" already. I searched "google" again, and it was in an another address, not `0x01960064` anymore. The address changed.

Why did it work like this? :(

Comment: Please format your question properly, this is unreadable.

Comment: Have you thought that maybe there are many copies of the string in the browsers memory? and that maybe not all of them are related to what's being shown on screen? And that the window needs to be redrawn after you change the correct place?

Comment: This should be closed in my opinion; it's pretty much a question about reverse engineering Google Chrome and as such doesn't belong here.

Comment: @szczurcio i typed in my phone,it displays well in app,but not that well in browser.  :(  i'm trying to format this.

Comment: @szczurcio: why should reverse engineering questions be off-topic?

Comment: The source code of Google Chrome is (more or less) open. There is no need for reverse engineering.

Comment: @Lucas Because there's a special StackExchange site dedicated to reverse engineering: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JoachimPileborg actually i changed more than one address,but still not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strings are probably objects, and thus probably heap allocated.

The heaps would probably be managed by some garbage collector, so even if you did locate the correct address, there is no guarantee that the same object is there when you try to inject the new data..

In case you don't know this, garbage collectors will often defragment the heap, after cleanups..

Getting around this issue would require you to make sure that all threads are paused in the browser process.

Comment: why did the string move to another address after I called WriteProcessMemory? if i remove  this call,the address keeps still and does not change. thx!

Comment: GC(garbage collector) will work only when the object is not referenced any more.maybe when a web page is not closed, the object is not released yet?

Comment: GC works when a timer runs out, and if any object is not used anymore, it can defragment memory and move objects.. I do not know why WriteProcessMemory could move data. simply stating that this is a bad idea since this is a background process that will give you problems'

Comment: finally i did it using fiddler core library instead.Thanks!